# Class Object Define Sort Behavior

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Sorry if this is a trivial question but I'm pretty new to java, but I've looked into ArrayLists and Collections.  I think a collection is somehow how I need to go, but I'm unfamiliar and want to ask here.

I looked into [comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interfaces, but I'm not sure that this is where I need to go or not.  I'm probably asking a duplicate question but I've tried googling for overloaded sort operators java, or user object sortable lists, etc.. I'm probably missing a key java term.

Let's say I have a user defined type

```
class UserObject {
      private long timestamp;
      private String thing;
      private String otherthing;
      public UserObject(long ts) { timestamp = ts ); 
}
```

Is there a data container that can hold UserObjects and sort them based on the private member timestamp?  In lua I could edit the tables metamethod value and I think in C++ you can overload the equality operators.

Something where I do:

```
class UserObject {
    ...
    public boolean lessThan(UserObject rhs) {
        return timestamp < rhs.timestamp;
    }
}

ArrayList<UserObject> MyObjects;
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    MyObjects.add(new UserObject(10-i))
}

Collections.sort(MyObjects); //should invert the order
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your class implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
class UserObject implements Comparable<UserObject> {
    private long timestamp;
    ...

    // returns int < 0 (this before o), int > 0 (o before this), or 0 
    public int compareTo(UserObject o) { 
        return Long.compare(this.timestamp, o.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Then you can sort any `List<UserObject>` implementing Collection `s` via `Collections.sort(s)`.

Implementing the `Comparable` interface gives your class a 'natural' order. If you need any other order, you can write a custom `Comparator`:

```
public class UserObjectComp implements Comparator<UserObject> {
    public int compare(UserObject o1, UserObject o2) {
        // return < 0, 0, or > 0 
    }
}
```

This you can pass as a second argument to `sort()`:

```
List<UserObject> l = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(l, new UserObjectComp());
```

Comment: +1 for using `Long.compare()`! This is actually the correct way to compare two longs. One thing, though, no need for `self` in Java :p Also, your comment is inexact: the comparison will actually return strictly less than (or greater than) 0, it does not have to return -1 or 1.

Comment: @fge Valid points, updated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a collection that would sort it for you. It is called [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). Your UserObject class must implement a comparable interface (Just like @schwobaseggl user showed in his answer) or you can create your Set by passing it your own implementation of [Comporator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). In ether case the set will always keep your sequence sorted. Just keep in mind that every time you modify your set it performs sorting which may be expansive performance-wise. So you might want to keep your collection in a regular list and sort it on demand when you need it by using `Collections.sort(s)` method